# displacement between two images using opencv surf

Tags: c++, opencv

I am working on image processing with OPENCV.
I want to find the x,y  and the rotational displacement between two images in OPENCV.
I have found the features of the images using SURF and the features have been matched.
Now i want to find the displacement between the images. How do I do that? Can RANSAC be useful here?

regards,
shiksha

Comment: If the scene is planar or can be modeled that way (e.g. if everything is very far away), find a homography with ransac.

Comment: RANSAC is mainly for filtering the features right? How to find the displacement? And the images are taken from a down facing camera at a height of around 1m.

Comment: standard method is to `match` the features of both images, which gives you possible correspondences. If you are sure that those matches are correct you don't need RANSAC. Just compute `estimateRigidTransform` from 3 correct image correspondences and you will get a matrix that consists of a `translation` part, a `rotation` part and a uniform `scaling` part.
If there are wrong correspondences (so called outlier), it's highly recommended to use RANSAC which will look like (choose randomly 3 correspondences and compute transform from them, accept only if enough inlier, try again otherwise)

Comment: If you don't want to compute RANSAC on your own, try `findHomography` and use some `decomposition` methods to split rotation and translation parts from the rest, but be aware that that's often not as stable as using affine/rigid transformations instead of full affine ones.

Comment: @Micka the rigid transform can be get from three 3D correspondences, not 2D. You can get the transform from more 2D correspondences (depending on the algorithm), but the translation will be up to scale (so you get the vector, but you don't now the magnitude).

Comment: @ChronoTrigger full affine has 6 dof = 3 x 2D corresp. Rigid transf. is 4 dof if I dont think wrong, so 2 x 2D should be enough already? Edit: opencv doc says 5 dof

Comment: @Micka for rigid transformation I thought you meant 3D rigid transformation (6 dof), sorry.

Comment: Mika, what rigid transform and scaling have in common?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rotation and two translations are three unknowns so your min number of matches is two (since each match delivers two equations or constraints). Indeed imagine a line segment between two points in one image and the corresponding (matched) line segment in another image. The difference between segments' orientations gives you a rotation angle. After you rotated just use any of the matched points to find translation. Thus this is 3DOF problem that requires two points. It is called Euclidean transformation or rigid body transformation or orthogonal Procrustes.

Using Homography (that is 8DOF problem ) that has no close form solution and relies on non-linear optimization is a bad idea. It is slow (in RANSAC case) and inaccurate since it adds 5 extra DOF. RANSAC is only needed if you have outliers. In the case of pure noise and overdetrmined system (more than 2 points) your optimal solution that minimizes the sum of squares of geometric distance between matched points is given in a close form by:

**Problem statement: min([R*P+t-Q]<sup>2</sup>)**, R-rotation, t-translation
**Solution: R = VU<sup>T</sup>, t = R*Pmean-Qmean**
where X=P-Pmean; Y=Q-Qmean and we take [SVD](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=svd#SVD) to get X*Y<sup>T</sup>=ULV<sup>T</sup>; all matrices have data points as columns. For a gentle intro into rigid transformations see [this](http://igl.ethz.ch/projects/ARAP/svd_rot.pdf)